# Does vector normalization alter distance relationships?

Tags: normalization, distance

Simple question, but one I'm struggling to visualize. Does L2 normalization affect the Euclidean distance computation between pairs of vectors? I can't imagine it would, because it's just the length of the vectors rather than the angle between them, but when I worked out the math I couldn't see that reflected.

I am doing $||v_1 - v_2||_2$.

In order words, if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are closer than $v_1$ and $v_{i \ne 2}$ will that be altered by comparing normalized $v_i$ to normalized $v_j$?

Comment: Suppose I am located one meter along a road from its start and you are a thousand meters down the road.  Although our distance is 999 meters, our *normalized* vectors are identical. When you normalize a nonzero vector you throw away all information about its length.  How could that *not* affect distance calculations?

Comment: @whuber: I understand. I mean comparing un-normalized vector pairs to normalized vector pairs. I mean the relationship between them. I edited the OP to hopefully clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take

$$ v_1 = (0, 1) $$
$$ v_2 = (1, 0) $$
$$ v_3 = (50, 50) $$

After normalization

$$ v_1' = (0, 1) $$
$$ v_2' = (1, 0) $$
$$ v_3' = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) $$

You can easily visualize where these lay on the unit circle, and verify that $v_3'$ is now closer to $v_1'$ than $v_2'$.